# Can't login to Facebook

Tags: facebook, login, facebook-profile

I'm having problems to enter my Facebook account, both from the website and the Android app.

When I tried to enter, I was redirected to a page where I was told that I could not login and that I had to upload a photo of my face, that would have been analyzed then deleted:

[image]

I tried to do so, but I still can't access my profile, I'm told that they need to analyze it and that for security reasons I would be disconnected:

[image]

**Has anybody else experienced this problem? How can it be solved? And, the most important thing, what has caused this?** I did nothing strange, just regular use.

Comment: _I was redirected to a page_, what is that page? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Are you still facing the same issue? Is it still redirecting to same page, if not what error you are getting now?

Comment: They already have given you answer. You have to wait to come back them. There is no other option.

Comment: Ok but what caused this, and how much time does it take to solve it? I'm trying to gather information from other  users

Comment: It is for security, they might have detected some unusual activity from your account or someone else were truing to do something. Generally it takes one week to one month. No fix time.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I hope that everything will go smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have followed the procedure, now wait for the Facebook response. They will come back (mostly). Generally it takes one week to one month (my experience, there is no fix time).

This happens due to security reason. When Facebook detect some unusual activity which doesn't follow the [Community Standards](https://www.facebook.com/communitystandards/?ref=u2u), they ask for identification and other proofs, during the verification period they disabled the account.

Here is the similar problem: https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=1578391448850443

If you didn't hear from Facebook for a long time, you can use this link: [My Personal Account was Disabled](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/260749603972907)

Comment: Thank you, I'll wait then. Honestly I can't understand what could have caused this, I use it sparingly and without breaking any of the rules of their Community Standards.