# Facebook wants my phone number to let me in

Tags: facebook, login, account-recovery, user-accounts

All of a sudden I'm unable to access my Facebook profile, I'm asked to provide my phone number to be sent a verification code.

I don't want to give Facebook my phone number, but I can't find another way to enter.

I'm redirected to this page https://www.facebook.com/checkpoint/?next where I can't do anything, this is pretty annoying, I'm not given any other option or explaination.

> [image]

**What can I do? Is there some way to recover access without giving out my number? And if this is not possible, is there a way to delete it after having gained back access to my profile again?**

---

I already had a (possibly) [similar problem](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/113316/101779) some time ago, but I was not forced to give my number. And I can't understand why this kind of problem pops up.

Comment: 1) Did you gave your number to facebook before? I guess not, but to be sure. 2) You got any email or message on the website that says that you're locked? 3) Have you tried from another platform app in addition to the browser?

Comment: 1) No, I know that this is silly 'cause they probably already know even how many times I go to the toilet, but no. 2) No, no email whatsoever, only what you can see on the screenshot. There was a screen before this one where I was briefly told that I had to verify my account, a "ok" button (it was in italian, I don't know exactly what the original english text could have been), but it was just a notice, no option, nothing to select, nothing at all. 3) Yes, tried from the Android App, same story even here, they want the phone number.

Comment: Now I know that it is kinda absurd, but if someone does not own a mobile phone (not my case, just hypothesizing), what is he supposed to do?

Comment: It sounds weird, because from what I know and all the information that I found - it's used as a layer of verification (and data collection of course), but not mandatory. Maybe you can try enter the forgot password page and try sending a reset link to your email?

Comment: And they probably do know your phone (from your phone, friends, Whatsapp, etc.), but I understand why you don't want to give it.

Comment: I've tried to reset the password, and the procedure seemed to work (I got an email with a verification code), but when I try to login, the page where I'm asked to provide my number appears again... This is pretty annoying, and it does not really seem like something they do to protect my interests, more like bullying... I still don't understand what can have caused this

Comment: I really don't know what else you can try, maybe another browsers? try to reset and say it wasn't you? By the way, [look at this facebook app permission](https://imgur.com/a/RTx9K), sadly, we can't escape :(

Comment: Could not find another solution, I had to insert the number to go in again; I've removed it afterwards from the settings, but we know that this is not giving any guarantee...